# Timeout when connecting with Amazon RDS SQL Server database

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-rds

I am creating an Amazon RDS Microsoft SQL Server database using an AWS CloudFormation template. It took some time to create and I connected to the database successfully, but it sometimes throws this exception:

> Service was unable to open new database connection when requested.
>   SqlException: A connection was successfully established with the server, but then an error occurred during the pre-login handshake. (provider: SSL Provider, error: 0 - The wait operation timed out.)

Here is the code which I am using to create database using AWS template:

```
"ProductDatabase":{
         "Type":"AWS::RDS::DBInstance",
         "Condition":"isNewDatabase",
         "Properties":{
            "AllocatedStorage":{
               "Ref":"AllocatedStorage"
            },
            "DBInstanceClass":"db.m4.large",
            "Port":"1433",
            "StorageType":"gp2",
            "BackupRetentionPeriod":"7",
            "DBName":"",
            "DBSubnetGroupName": {
             "Ref": "DatabaseSubnetGroup"
           },
            "MasterUsername":{
               "Ref":"DBUserName"
            },
            "MasterUserPassword":{
               "Ref":"DBPassword"
            },
            "Engine":"sqlserver-se",
            "EngineVersion":"13.00.4422.0.v1",
            "LicenseModel":"license-included",
            "VPCSecurityGroups" : [ { "Ref" : "rdsDBSecurityGroup" }  ],
            "Tags": [
             {
              "Key": "Name",
              "Value": { "Ref": "AWS::StackName" }
             }
          ]
         }
      },
```

Comment: Does it fail _every time_, or are you saying that it randomly fails? If it is random, can you tell us more about how often the error happens?

Comment: yes it randomly fails , it happens onces in 8 to 10 attempts

Comment: What are you doing to get that error? Is it _after_ the CloudFormation template has finished deploying and you are trying to connect to the database? What if you wait a little longer before trying to connect?